# Create Outlook Calendar with Powershell NOT on default calendar

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have a simple script that will create an Outlook Calendar Item (found online) and it will create a calendar item just fine, but it puts it on my default calendar. How can I get it to put it on a specific calendar? This is what I have.

```
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application
    $CalItem = "1"
    $newAppt = $outlook.CreateItem($CalItem)
    $newAppt.Body = "Test Body222"
    $newAppt.Subject = "Test Subject222"
    $newAppt.Start = $OutObject.StartDate
    $newAppt.End = $OutObject.ImpEndDate
    $newAppt.BusyStatus = 0
    $newAppt.Save()
```

Comment: There is a `SaveAs()` Method, maybe if you figure out where to point it, you could save it in another calendar. (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.saveas)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it happen with this

```
# Instantiate a new Outlook object
$ol = new-object -ComObject "Outlook.Application"
# Map to the MAPI namespace
$MyNameSpace = $ol.getnamespace("mapi")
#Default Calendar Folder
$MyDefCal = $MyNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder("olFolderCalendar")
#Folder or "Calendar" I want to add the Item to
$MySharedCal = $MyDefCal.Folders.Item("TestCal") 

#Create the Calendar Item
$MyItem = $MySharedCal.Items.Add(1)
$MyItem.Body = "Test"
$MyItem.Subject = "This Is A Test"
$MyItem.Start = "03/01/2019"
$MyItem.AllDayEvent = 1
$MyItem.ReminderSet = 0
$MyItem.BusyStatus = 0
$MyItem.Save()
```

Thanks to Dimitry for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Application.CreateItem` (whcih always uses the appropriate default folder), open the target folder programmatically and use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`.

Comment: Thanks and helpful. I am able to get the folder path. Care to show an example of the `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` ?

Comment: $newAppt = YourMAPIFolder.Items.Add

Comment: Or are you asking how to open the non-default folder? Where is it located relative to the default Calendar folder and/or the root folder?

Comment: I am able to get the path to the folder I want to use with this. `$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi");` `$CalFold = $mapi.Folders.Item(2).Folders.Item(8).Folders.Item(1) | Select FolderPath;` it returns the path that I want to use.

Comment: $CalFold is what you want, not the path. And do not hardcode the integer indices - use names instead - Item() take either an integer index or a name (string).  Again, where is the folder located compared to other default folders (such as Calendar)?

Comment: The folder is located under the default calendar folder `\\My-Default\Calendar\This-Is-Where-I-Want-To-Add`

Comment: Then you should retrieve the default Calendar folder using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar), then open the child folder using CalendarFolder.Folders.Item("This-Is-Where-I-Want-To-Add")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189260/discussion-between-eric-and-dmitry-streblechenko).